# PostgreSQL + Openshift: Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, openshift, liquibase

I am trying to run the liquibase update from `Openshift` machine that I have. It looks like

```
> java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.1.1/liquibase-core-3.1.1.jar --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=wildfly/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war --changeLogFile=liquibase/changelog.xml --url="jdbc:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL/mydb" --username=$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME --password=OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD update
```

and I see the following error

```
Liquibase update Failed: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql://admin:29asDVjpFxYl6@127.8.201.2:5432/mydb with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

What is going wrong here?

I am using the following `postgreSQL` dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And what version of Postgres is the server running?

Comment: version 9.2 is what Openshift provides

Comment: Then perhaps you should use a 9.2 driver.

Comment: The part `admin:29asDVjpFxYl6@127.8.201.2:5432/mydb` in the URL is invalid for the Postgres driver. The syntax is `//host:port/database` (only a single colon `:` is possible). Either Openshift needs a special driver or your URL is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there were 2 issues that were fixed as following

a.) using postgres 9.2 driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

b.) using the following url

```
--url="jdbc:postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT/mydb"
```